# Netlink implementation for the Android NDK

Tags: android, sockets, android-ndk, netlink, inet

I have a requirement for similar task as mentioned in [this link.](https://kristrev.github.io/2013/07/26/passive-monitoring-of-sockets-on-linux/). Passive monitoring of sockets in Android. One way is parsing the /proc/net/{tcp,udp,...} tables. But we have to keep on reading continuously for keep on monitoring; which is not efficient way. As it will be a mobile device app, it will eat up the battery as it requires CPU Time for keep on monitoring for time interval (say 1 sec).

But, I am looking for an event based approach. As I googled about the same, I ended with NETLINK for monitoring the sockets. But I observe that Android NDK doesn't have support for the

```
#include <linux/sock_diag.h>
#include <linux/inet_diag.h>
#include <linux/unix_diag.h>
#include <linux/packet_diag.h>
#include <linux/netlink_diag.h>
```

Does anyone tried using NETLINK in Android for monitoring the INET sockets? If so please share the information.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:
I tried copy pasting the above mentioned files in the "jni" folder and built using ndk-build. Building was successful and also no crashes at the runtime. But, socket creation of type

```
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_INET_DIAG)
```

is failing with error EACCES(13) - Permission to create a socket of the specified type and/or protocol is denied.

Any suggestions how to proceed further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android Lollipop, Security Enhanced Linux (SELinux) in Android is enabled in "enforce" mode. By observing/looking at the sandbox definitions [Android Source Code - SE Policy](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sepolicy/) of the app.te (Below pasted excerpt), there will not be any supports for the netlink sockets.

## app.te

```
# Privileged netlink socket interfaces.
 
neverallow appdomain
 
    self:{
 
        netlink_socket
 
        netlink_firewall_socket
 
        netlink_tcpdiag_socket
 
        netlink_nflog_socket
 
        netlink_xfrm_socket
 
        netlink_audit_socket
 
        netlink_ip6fw_socket
 
        netlink_dnrt_socket
 
    } *;
```

Comment: It's no longer the case that apps can't create netlink socket. Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/d31936f89c49bc5c54b84bd5095f3c417da14935%5E%21/#F1

Answer (score -1):

i think, your app should have root permision!

Comment: While this may help OP, it's better to add more details, explanation, examples, etc.  Please [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)