# Cannot bind() netlink socket when targeting Android API 30

Tags: android, android-ndk, netlink

I have been using the following for quite some time to create a netlink socket:

```
NetLinkLocalNetworkInfo::NetLinkSocket::NetLinkSocket() :
fd(0)
{
    fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create NetLink socket");
    }

    struct sockaddr_nl addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;

    int err = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if(err < 0)
    {
        close(fd);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to bind NetLink socket");
    }
}
```

This is used in part of the networking logic we have in place to perform automatic NAT traversal using [ICE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245). When targeting API 30, the call to `bind` now returns -1 and `errno` is "Permission Denied".

A change in behavior for apps that target API 30 now means that `bind()` is a restricted call. (There's a document somewhere on the Google Developer page, but I'll be darned if I can find it again. It used to live [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mac-11-plus), but that page has changed since I first came across this issue a few months ago.) Supposedly this is supposed to affect all apps targeting API 30, but I've found that only apps targeting API 30 *and* running on a device (physical or emulator) running Android 11 are affected. My notes from when I first encountered this also mention that article suggesting using [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager), but that would require either coming up with some way to pass the information down to native code or having the native code call into the Android platform code via JNI. I'm fine with either of those if that's what has to happen, but I'm wondering if there's another alternative I'm not aware of.

I also saw [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148536/netlink-implementation-for-the-android-ndk), but there is a link in one of the answers indicating that it should be possible, at least up until API 30.

Now that we aren't allowed to call `bind()`, what other options are available?

Comment: If you just do without that call... Why should you bind?

Comment: To bind the socket `fd` to the sockaddr_nl `addr`

Comment: But why? I never bind a socket.

Comment: How would you go about gathering information about the device's network interfaces? I honestly don't remember why we're doing it this way. It's been like this since we implemented it 5 years ago. If you have a different way I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution to this. Turns out we were using NetLink sockets to discover network interface address information because `ifaddrs` was not available (or, not fully implemented, or something like that - nobody here could remember exactly why we couldn't use it) on Android at the time. As of API 24 `ifaddrs` is now available. We switched our implementation to use `ifaddrs`. As long as you're minimum supported version is API 24 or later you can do the same.

Comment: May i Please know what exactly you have done? I am facing the issue with NETLINK socket bind. What is ifaddrs and how to incorporate it?

Comment: `ifaddrs` is a utility in the NDK (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/ndk/+/dev/platform/sysroot/usr/include/ifaddrs.h). The `ifaddrs` struck contains the interface information. You basically just create an `ifaddrs` struct and then pass it to `getifaddrs()`, which will populate the fields. `ifa_name` is the interface name, `ifa_addr` is a `sockaddr`, etc. The `ifaddrs.h` header has the documentation you need.

Comment: Thank you very much